# Se possuir esta palavra na resposta do curl, print "OK"

Tags: python, request

Fiz um curl em python para verificar algumas informações do meu cliente, está ocorrendo tudo bem, a resposta da minha api é json, gostaria de saber como faço pra caso a api possua, por exemplo "userId", ele amostra-se um "OK" no console.

```
 import requests


url = "https://minhaapi.com/v1/login/username"

querystring = {"countryCode":"BR"}

payload = "username=user&password=teste123&clientVersion=2.4.9-undefined"
headers = {
    'Content-Type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    'x-requested-with': "XMLHttpRequest",
    'x-tidal-token': "wdgaB1CilGA-S_s2"
    }

response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers, params=querystring)

print(response.text)



Resposta da minha API(Quando o usuário loga com as informações no curl): 



{"userId":57261722,"sessionId":"5b1ada5b-addf-4804-a55e-a12f36959ff1","countryCode":"BR"}
```

Tentei este código, mas não consegui:

```
for url in response.text:
        if 'userId' in url.lower():
            print ("OK")
```

Quero só que imprima na tela "OK" quando o curl apresentar a resposta em json acima (que é quando o user loga), e se aparecer uma mensagem diferente ele imprima "Erro" na tela

Comment: json, amigo....

Comment: Por favor, desfaça sua edição e volte a pergunta a sua forma original. A pergunta original é totalmente diferente e a resposta aceita reflete isso. É importante deixar as perguntas em suas formas originais porque assim outras pessoas com dúvidas parecidas podem chegar nela através de buscas. Não há problema em criar uma nova pergunta pra fazer uma pergunta diferente.

Comment: Pronto amigo, poderia tentar me ajudar na outra pergunta ? Obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> for url in response.text:
>         if 'userId' in url.lower():
>             print ("OK")
> ```

Aqui você vê se `userId` está em `url.lower()`. Isso nunca resultará em True porque o `I` em `userId` é maiúsculo, e você compara isso com a versão minúscula de `url`.

`url` também não vai ser uma string; `response.text` é uma string, e quando se itera sobre uma string com um `for`, você obtém caracteres individuais. Recomendo que tente botar um `print(url)` antes do if pra ter uma ideia do que está acontecendo.

Já que sua API retorna um JSON, você não precisa lidar com `response.text`, pode usar o método `.json()` pra transformar a resposta em um dicionário Python. A partir daí, pode verificar se `userId` é uma chave no dicionário:

```
if 'userId' in response.json():
    print('OK')
else:
    print('ERRO')
```

---

Você também deve usar um dicionário pra passar o seu payload, e não uma string:

```
payload = {'username': 'user',
           'password': 'teste123',
           'clientVersion': '2.4.9-undefined'}
```

Comment: Obrigado, Pedro. Só mais uma coisinha, eu tenho uma lista em .txt no formato email|senha dos meus clientes e quero verificar a integridade de alguns cadastros. Eu queria criar uma variável que pegasse linha por linha e mudasse no payload do curl o email e a senha, entendeu ? Por exemplo, ele lesse o .txt e testa-se os cadastros um por um, linha por linha.

Comment: Tipo: cliente1@hotmail.com|cliente1

Comment: cliente2@gmail.com|cliente2 e por aí vai

Comment: @Gennie pode criar uma nova pergunta e incluir o que já tentou e por que não deu certo?

Comment: Irei editar o tópico.

Comment: @Gennie essa pergunta já está respondida e é sobre um assunto diferente. Não tem problema criar uma nova pergunta, já que as duas são pouco relacionadas.